# Textures not showing on animation model?

Tags: texturing, .fbx, three.js, blenderkit

*PREFACE*: I am a programmer, *not* an artist.  If I ask something that seems obvious too, this is why.

I bought two animation models from TurboSquid.  Both FBX models.  You can see them here:

[image]

The animation model on the left (Tarologist Robot), shows its textures properly.  As you can, the animation model to the right (Fighter Drone) does not.  It is plain white.  I opened the `Fighter Drone` FBX file in Blender and it does have the textures, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Here is the TurboSquid page for the `Fighter Done` model:
https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3d-fighter-drone-model-1487327

And here is what it is supposed to look (default texture set):

[image]

However they don't seem to appear on the actual model.  When I open the `Tarologist Robot` FBX file in Blender **I do see the purple textures on the model** in the Blender canvas, but when I open the `Fighter Drone` I do not on the fighter drone.  At least to me, it looks like a uniform drab grey..

Here is the directory of the exported FBX file:

Is this just because I don't know how to use Blender (I really don't), or did the artist/animator that sold the model on TurboSquid, expect the buyer to do the final step of applying the textures themselves?  If so, is it a simple procedure to apply the textures that I could do myself and if so, how?

The `Tarologist Robot` animation model also came with alternate texture sets.  But if my theory is right about unapplied textures, then I'm wondering if the artist for that model applied one of the texture sets as a "default", saving me this trouble I'm having with the `Fighter Drone` model?.

Note: I found a post about a somewhat similar problem:

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/texture-of-fbx-model-is-shown-only-black/26981/3

So I added this to my code for loading the `Fighter Drone`:

```js
                fbxMOdel.traverse(
                    child => {
                        if (child.isMesh)
                            child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
                })
```

But it did *not* help.

---

**Bonus question:**  Where can I find reliable Blender animator/artists for hire to help with the problems I'm see to run into fairly often with purchased models?  I've asked this question many times in different forums, and for some odd reason I have never gotten an answer.

Comment: You need to check the materials of the bot. A purple color indicates that Blender cannot find the image textures. According to the description, the drone comes with 6 PBR textures (albedo/color, metallic, roughness, normal, and emissive maps.) These are PNG image files. Have a look at the *Shader Editor* and check the materials from the list (*var_1* to *var_5* ). You need to connect the image textures with an *Image Texture* node to the *Principled BSDF* node. Connect the *albedo* with the *Color* slot, the metallic image with the *Metallic* slot, etc.

Comment: About the bonus question: Try https://www.blenderartists.org They have a forum, including subforums for paid and volunteer work.